# WPF: как настроить/вернуть в начальное состояние/починить дизайнер после обновления студии?

Tags: c#, wpf

Версия студии: MVS Preview 16.8.30509.190

Некоторое время поработав с версткой запустил установку обновления для студии, после которой дизайнер перестал показывать свойства датаконтекста в области привязки.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
```

Свойство Test будет отображаться в выпадающих списках только в течение первых 10-20 секунд после перезапуска студии или перезагрузки проекта. По прошествии этого времени в списках перестают отображаться вообще все свойства, принадлежащие классу вьюмодели.
При этом не важно, каким образом я задаю датаконтекст:
имитируя через DesignInstance

```
<Window d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=vm:MainWindowViewModel}"> </Window>
```

или указывая влоб

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Разницы нет. Также это происходит только в одном проекте, в свежесозданных такого не наблюдал.

Собственно, у меня появилась мысль, что обновление затронуло некоторые связанные с дизайнером параметры, которые, я думаю, можно вернуть к прежнему состоянию, да вот только где мне эти параметры найти?

Comment: Чистить проект пробовали? Студия очень криво работает со всякими привязками и прочим, очень часто багует и надо чистить, либо пересобирать. Попробуйте закрыть студию, удалить в проекте `bin` и `obj`, можете еще ее папку, которая начинается на точку (я обычно не удаляю). После откройте проект, ПКМ по нему - пересобрать. Ну и проверяйте, работает или нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ С кривой работой студии я давно знаком, привычные мне способы решения типовых багов не дали положительного результата: смена платформы, очистка проекта, смена разрядности, выгрузка проекта, перемещение ранее указанных вами папок, пересборка и так далее.

Comment: А на ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос вы планируете отреагировать? У меня студия 16.7.3 сейчас, выше указанной проблемы не наблюдаю.

Comment: @aepot , кстати, да. Ваш вариант сильно помог

Comment: Укажите версию студии. Используете ли вы в этом проекте NuGet пакеты? Какие? Покажите xaml разметку (целиком), приведите конкретный пример. Что будет, если разметку "как есть" скопировать в другой проект? Дополните вопрос, используйте редактирование.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался, в чем была проблема:
Обновление затронуло параметры конструктора и каким-то непонятным мне образом поменяло платформу решения на каждом проекте на х64.
Собственно, смена х64 на Any CPU и включение кода проекта позволило дизайнеру полноценно отображать свойства вьюмодели, а сам конструктор снова начал показывать актуальные данные и выполнять асинхронные задачи

[image: Фрагмент окна студии]

Comment: Вы используете .NET 5? Если нет, то лучше разрабатывать под релизной версией студии, так как Preview версия может быть нестабильна.